# Certificates expire without warning

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate, certificate-authority

A while back, we set up an internal microsoft certificate server to issue certificates to our internal servers.  However, when a certificate expires, we do not realize it until we start getting errors in our applications.

Is there a way to set up the certificate services to generate e-mail notifications when certificates are about to expire?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that software, but if you can't find a built in method for monitoring certificate expiry, look into `check-expire`: http://novosial.org/openssl/check-expire/. It's for a Unix environment, so if you lack any compatible OS installs, you could try looking into running it under Cygwin or MinGW.